# Join transactional table to create a transaction statement

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, join

I have a system to give loans to users using MySQL for local DB and MsSQL on live server, loan records are stored on the Loans table once approved and the user receives a loan it is stored in the Disbursement table as the user repay the loan in installment it is recorded in the Deposits table, Tables are as shown below

Loans: user_id, loan_code, loan_amt

Deposits: loan_code, deposit_amount, deposit_date

Disbursement: loan_code, dis_amount, dis_date

I am having a challenge to create a statement of the a user's last 10 transaction using MySQL (or MsSQL) being either the disbursement or deposit, I would like to create a result as below

Statement: Date, Transaction Type (deposit or disbursement), Loan Code, Amount

Comment: What did you try and what was the error you got?

Comment: You need to decide....is this mysql or sqlserver? They are NOT the same thing and the queries will likely be a little different.

Comment: Developing with software that is different than production is very likely to cause problems.  This question is an excellent example because sql server and mySql have different syntax for "top n" queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're trying to effectively merge data from two tables, you'll need to use a `UNION` operator.

This is for MS SQL Server. MySQL uses the `LIMIT` keyword instead of `TOP`, but I believe that the rest should work the same.

```
SELECT TOP 10
    transaction_date,
    transaction_type,
    loan_code,
    amount
FROM
(
    SELECT
        DEP.deposit_date AS transaction_date,
        'Deposit' AS transaction_type,
        L.loan_code,
        DEP.deposit_amount AS amount
    FROM
        Deposits DEP
    INNER JOIN Loans L ON L.loan_code = DEP.loan_code

    UNION ALL  -- UNION would work also, but UNION ALL will perform slightly better

    SELECT
        DIS.dis_date,
        'Disbursement' AS transaction_type,
        L.loan_code,
        DIS.dis_amount
    FROM
        Disbursements DIS
    INNER JOIN Loans L ON L.loan_code = DIS.loan_code
) SQ
ORDER BY
    transaction_date DESC
```

Comment: If you want to use another column in the outer SQL statement then you'll need to add it to the column lists in each of the SQL statements in the subquery.